# get list of element with slot attribute vue

Tags: vuejs2, slot

i have in my parent a custom tag `<datatable>` with slot references in it:

```
 <datatable> 
        <div slot="week"> 5</div>
        <div slot="day"> monday</div>
    </datatable>
```

Is it possible to get an array of the slot names?

tried: `document.querySelectorAll('[slot]');`

But all i get is an empty nodelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the array like this (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-slots):

```html
 <datatable ref="comp"> 
        <div slot="week"> 5</div>
        <div slot="day"> monday</div>
    </datatable>
```

```js
console.log(Object.keys(this.$refs.comp.$slots));
```